# Most efficient way to mass delete CollaborationGroups after 24 hours?

Tags: chatter, collaborationgroup

I want to purge all CollaborationGroups (chatter groups) every 24 hours. What is the most efficient way to do this? Creating an apex job?

Answer (score 2):

There are few options I can think of

1.Batch Apex with a Scheduler class .This is the best method for sure as all code resides inside the platform.

2.You can use command line dataloader and schedule a job to do this .You will need your own server where you can run the utility .

3.Use middleware like Informatica On Demand or JitterBit or Talend Middleware if your company already uses them for some sort of data processing .

Above all batch apex seems to be easiest way to get this done .

Comment: Thanks. What if the problem was to have each CollaborationGroup to be purged in 24 hours (e.g. each chatter group has 24 hours to live). What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Efficient in terms of speed or manging code? .Batch apex is a really great way

Comment: Efficient as in how can I have an apex job that only executes every time a CollaborationGroup has lived for 24 hours? I know I can use a batch apex to run a cleanup every X hours or at X time, but how would I have a apex job run to do cleanup only every time a group has lived for 24 hours

Comment: You have created date on group feeds .Just query records that are greater than today -1 and less than today ?makes sense